# query taking too much time

Tags: sql, optimization

Below query taking too much time for exectuion. The is index on Date of Birth. Is there anything more to do make it fast

```
SELECT * FROM Member_dtls WHERE
DATEADD(year, 10, DateOfBirth) < GETDATE()
```

Comment: You are using a function on that DateOfBirth, so an index is ignored

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, make it [SARGable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) (here by avoiding expression on column that is indexed):

```
SELECT * FROM Member_dtls 
WHERE DateOfBirth < DATEADD(year, -10, GETDATE())
                    -- this part is "constant"
```